# checking a list contains both element or only one

Tags: groovy

Is there a ninja trick for checking a list contains both elements? I am thinking about something like any

Basically I want the code below to be rewritten:

```
List<String> elements = ["first", "fourth"]
List<String> longList = ["first", "second", "third", "fourth"]
boolean haveAll = elements ? true : false

elements.each { String element ->
    haveAll &= longList.any {element==it}
}

assert haveAll == true

longList = ["first", "second", "third"]
elements.each { String element ->
    haveAll &= longList.any {element==it}
}

assert haveAll == false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt this qualifies as a *ninja trick*, but it seems to do the job

```
List<String> longList = ["first", "second", "third", "fourth"]

boolean hasAll = longList.containsAll(["first", "fourth"])
boolean hasAny = ["not in long list", "first"].any {
  it in longList
}

// check that it worked 
assert hasAll && hasAny
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `every` and `any`:

```
def elements = ["first", "fourth"]
def longList = ["first", "second", "third", "fourth"]

assert elements.every { it in longList }
assert elements.any { it in longList }
```